# SharePoint2013 Add folder/sub folders to document library from outside SharePoint environment

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server, client-object-model, rest

My requirement is when a button clicked in my application(hosted on a different server), need to check folder exists with the named supplied. If not exits, able to create folder and sub folders in a given Document library.

So how to achieve above functionality and also what technologies(Rest_api / CSOM) should I use? Do I have to pass credentials also to create(permissions)?

I appreciate for your time and provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code sample using REST and the SharePoint Javascript cross-domain library to perform basic operations on document libraries and files:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/SharePoint-2013-Perform-ab9c4ae5